# How to collect special letters like "ᑕƘᏔ®✞ℍ"

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, special-characters

I'm scraping a social platform using selenium, and a lot of users use special characters like `HEᑕƘᏔ®✞ℍ`, fire Emojis and so on. These characters turn into questions marks like "`HE?????????`".

I've tried to use the decode and encode utilities but I've had absolutely no luck.
See here:

```
 WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string);
 WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string);
```

I get the feeling I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but have no idea where to start, as special character answers normally talk about Unicode, and I'm pretty sure this isn't relevant in this case.

**EDIT: 
This is how I'm fetching the content using selenium**

```
  title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"header- 
  section\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/h1")).Text;
```

Comment: Probably you are decoding in the wrong way text from html

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is looking at HTML decode and encode rather which replaces letters to make them HTML safe for example £ becomes `&pound;`

You want to look at text encoding, as this controls which characters are available with different characters sets giving you different characters. If a character is not available in the character set you are using it shows as a question mark or black block.

You can use `Encoding.Convert()` see [this discussion](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0440__I18N-Internationalization/ConvertUTF8fromUnicode.htm) for more info.

It is likely you will want to convert your input to UTF-8 text encoding to see the full character set.